# using didDismissCompletionHandler in MZFormSheetController

Tags: ios, completion-block

I'm using [MZFormSheetController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController) to present modals in my app. There is a situation where I want to present a second sheet controller right after I dismiss the first one. In order to do that, there is a [completion block](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController#completion-blocks), but I can't figure out how to actually use it.

The code looks like this:

```
[self mz_presentFormSheetController:formSheet
                               animated:YES
                      completionHandler:^(MZFormSheetController *formSheetController) {
                          formSheetController.didDismissCompletionHandler;
                      }];
```

in that completion handler, what am I supposed to do to get notified of the sheet dismissal so I can then call the second sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple, but not totally intuitive if you haven't spent some time in this type of environment.

```
[self mz_presentFormSheetController:formSheet
                               animated:YES
                      completionHandler:^(MZFormSheetController *formSheetController) {
                          formSheetController.didDismissCompletionHandler = ^(UIViewController *presentedViewController){
                                  [self presentOtherController];
                          };
                      }];
```